# htaccess block original file however allow rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following entries in my /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^signin.php - [L,gone]
RewriteRule ^sign-in/?$  /signin.php [L]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to allow the user to access `/sign-in` but not the original file `/signin.php`

I saw this other question however when I tried to implement the answer I get `gone` error on both `/sign-in` and `/signin.php`.

Referenced Question:
[Alias within htaccess, and block access to original file? (URL rewriting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925723/alias-within-htaccess-and-block-access-to-original-file-url-rewriting)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Reason for what you describe is that the rewriting engine takes _two_ passes in case of a request to `/sign-in`. You'd need to use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag to prevent that.

Comment: What I ask myself: why would you want to send a "gone" header here? Why not redirect the client?

Comment: @arkascha how would I redirect a user in this case? Say the user went to `/signin.php` is there a way to redirect the user to `/sign-in` ?

Comment: Sure there is. Actually that is pretty much standard. And hundreds of existing answers here on SO demonstrate exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect any direct requests for `/signin.php` to `/sign-in` and internally rewrite `/sign-in` back to `/signin.php` then you can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^signin\.php$ /sign-in [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sign-in$ signin.php [END]
```

The `END` flag (Apache 2.4) prevents any further loops by the rewrite engine, so prevents the rewritten URL being redirected back to `/sign-in`, which would otherwise cause a redirect loop.

The `END` flag is not required on the first rule, since an external redirect will trigger immediately. (The `L` flag is still required.)

You do not need the `RewriteBase` directive here.

I removed the optional trailing slash on `/sign-in` as this potentially creates a duplicate content issue. If you wish to allow an optional trailing slash then redirect to the canonical URL (*without* the trailing slash, or *with* if you prefer) instead.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I saw this other question however when I tried to implement the answer I get `gone` error on both `/sign-in` and `/signin.php`.
>
> Referenced Question:
> [Alias within htaccess, and block access to original file? (URL rewriting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925723/alias-within-htaccess-and-block-access-to-original-file-url-rewriting)

The Apache solution in the referenced answer is not quite correct. The answer would seem to have been "accepted" for the first part regarding doing this in PHP instead.

At the time of that question (2011), they would have been using Apache 2.2. The `END` flag was only introduced in Apache 2.4.

They would have needed to have done it like this, to prevent a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^about.php /about [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a short analysis of the referenced question.